# right floating doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Hi there i just want to know why my css `float:right;` didn't work ?

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YqoWMg)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there are one red div ( `.hm` ). This div should be right corner but it is floating left. What the problem on there anyone can help me in this regard ?

CSS

```
.header {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  padding:20px 0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background-color:#ffffff; 
}
.header_in {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.smatLogo {
  position:relative;
  float:left;   
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
   background-color:blue;
}
.smatLogo img {
  width:100%;   
}

.hm {
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  max-width:200px;
   background-color:red;
}

.mn {
  float:left;
  width:calc(100%/3 - 1px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100%/3 - 1px);
  width: -mox-calc(100%/3 - 1px);
  height:40px;  
}

.notif {
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
}

.exp{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;  
}

.user{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Remove display:flex from .header_in and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of `display:flex;` property set for the class `.header_in`.
And that is the correct behavior of a flex object.

So now your options remain either to not use the `flex` property or if you need the properties of the `flexbox` then you can use the solution given below .

In order to workaround that you shall have to use `margin-left: auto;` for the `.hm` class.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/PNrGqq)**

**Note:** This can also be done using `tables` but later down the line that same `table` will come back to bite you :D